# If $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are i.i.d. nonnegative integer-valued random variables with CDF $F(x)$, with $F(0)<1$. Is it true that $F(x)<1$ for all $x\geq0?$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Problem:** Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are i.i.d. nonnegative integer-valued random variables with common CDF $F(x)$. Assume that $F(0)<1$. Does it follow that $F(x)<1$ for all $x\geq0?$

---

Does anyone have a hint on how to get started on this problem? This is part of the following problem
Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are i.i.d. nonnegative integer-valued random variables with common CDF $F(x)$. Assume that $F(0)<1$ and let $F^{(n)}$ denote th $n$-fold
convolution of $F$. (This is the convolution of $n$ copies of $F$.)
$\textbf{a)}$ For each $x>0$ find a random variable $N_x$ for which $E[N_x]=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty F^{(n)}(x).$
$\textbf{b)}$ Show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty F^{(n)}(x)$ is finite for all $x\geq0.$
$\textbf{c)}$ Is the previous statement true if we don't assume that the $X_i$ are integer valued?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is $F^{(n)}$?

Comment: @angryavian It is the $n$-fold convolution of $F$ with itself

Comment: Strange question. What has i.i.d. to do with the question in your title? You are asking something about $F$ and all  that is relevant  is that the distribution is concentrated on non-negative integers. It has nothing to do with indepedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure this is the right question? Suppose $X_i \overset{i.i.d.}{\sim} Bernoulli(1/2)$. Then $F(0) = 1/2 < 1$ and $F(1) = 1$, so no it doesn't follow.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't true.  If $F(0)=0$ (for instance), it is possible for $F(x_0)=1$ for some discrete $0< x_0 < 1$ and $F(x) = 0$ otherwise.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't a CDF be nondecreasing?

Comment: You mean like mine?  (over the domain).

Comment: If $\ X\ $ is integer-valued, doesn't that imply that the only points of increase of $\ F_X\ $ must be integers? So how would it be possible for $\ F_X(0)=0\ $ and $\ F_X(x)>0\ $ for any $\ x\in[0,1)\ $?  You could, of course, have $\ F_X(1)=1\ $, which would still contradict $\ F_X(x)<1\ $ for all $\ x\ $.